# Inputting multiple values into a relational database field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a database application for a restaurant stock management system. I currently have two database tables, one for the ingredients, and one for each dish.

[Database tables and relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ncHW.png)

Each ingredient has a unique ID which is the PK of the table. And the 'ingredients' field in the DISH table is a foreign key linking to ingredient_ID. Each dish will obviously have many ingredients, but the ingredients can also belong to multiple dishes. I have read elsewhere about creating another table called ingredient_dish for example, but I'm not sure I fully understand how this works. Could somebody either point me in the right direction or attempt to explain please, and what sort of columns would I have in this joining table for the above tables?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships are best done with such an intermediate (or "bridge") table. The bridge table basically consists of the primary keys of the other tables to form a "bigger" foreign key, which allows you to implement a many-to-many relationship by providing primary key combinations.

Your use case (simplified) would necessitate tables like these:

```
dishes:
 dish_id | other_columns
-------------------------
       1 | ...
       2 | ...
       3 | ...

ingredients:
 ingredient_id | other_columns
-------------------------------
             1 | ...
             2 | ...
             3 | ...

dishes_ingredients_bridge:
 dish_id | ingredient_id
-------------------------
       1 | 1
       1 | 2
       2 | 2
       2 | 3
       3 | 3
```

This means you have 3 dishes and 3 ingredients, where

- dish 1 consists of ingredients 1 and 2
- dish 2 consists of ingredients 2 and 3
- dish 3 consists only of ingredient 3
- ingredient 1 is used only in dish 1
- ingredient 2 is used in dishes 1 and 2
- ingredient 3 is used in dishes 2 and 3

Also, make sure, the combinations in your bridge are unique (create a multi-column unique key). Omitting this usually doesn't result in big problems, but in some edge cases your application could behave in an undefined or unexpected way.

Now you can query (for example) all ingredients of dish 1 like this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM ingredients as i
LEFT JOIN dishes_ingredients_bridge dib
ON dib.ingredient_id = dib.ingredient_id
LEFT JOIN dishes as d
ON d.dish_id = dib.dish_id
```

"Connecting" a dish to an ingredient means adding a row to the bridge. "Disconnecting" a dish from an ingredient means deleting such rows, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver, this is for my Uni dissertation and you've just made it a whole lot clearer, the syntax for querying this wasn't something I was clear on, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck! :) I've just recognized a typo, I'll fix.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Many-to-Many relationship between Ingredients and Dishes, you may want Ingredient_Dish to be a Cross-Reference table.

Its fields would include ingredient_id, a foreign key to the Ingredients table, and dish_id, a foreign key to the Dish table. Set the primary key of this new table to the combination of both fields. A creation command might look like the following, tailor it to suit:

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient_Dish (
  ingredient_id INT    NOT NULL,
  dish_id       INT    NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Ingredients_by_dish PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id, dish_id))
ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Dish 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Ingredients FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES Ingredient (ingredient_id )
ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Dish
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Dishess FOREIGN KEY (dish_id) REFERENCES Dish (dish_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing a bridge table. It's the only way to describe a many-to-many relationship without concatenating values (which is a very nasty can of worms). I suggest you read this further:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/02/design-tip-142-building-bridges/

Hope it helps.